# Reading CouchBase Data From Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, couchbase

I was trying to read a sample data from Couchbase with Spark. Below is the error and the code that was run.

It seems I am getting the authentication error, the user name and the password mentioned are same used with the cbc commands.

```
package com.demo.sparkstreaming

import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.couchbase.spark._
/**
* Created by cloudera on 12/8/17.
*/
object SparkRead {



def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  // The SparkSession is the main entry point into spark
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("KeyValueExample")
    .master("local[*]") // use the JVM as the master, great for testing
    .config("spark.couchbase.nodes", "192.168.169.101") // connect to couchbase on hostname
    .config("spark.couchbase.bucket.travel-sample","") // open the travel-sample bucket with empty password
    .config("com.couchbase.username", "test")
    .config("com.couchbase.password", "****")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.sparkContext
    .couchbaseGet[JsonDocument](Seq("airline_10123")) // Load documents from couchbase
    .collect() // collect all data from the spark workers
    .foreach(println) // print each document content


 }
}
```

**ERROR LOGS**

> **com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.AuthenticationException: Authentication Failure**
>     at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.KeyValueAuthHandler.checkIsAuthed(KeyValueAuthHandler.java:288)
>     at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.KeyValueAuthHandler.channelRead0(KeyValueAuthHandler.java:173)
>     at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.KeyValueAuthHandler.channelRead0(KeyValueAuthHandler.java:52)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>     at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Looks like from your local windows machine, you tried to connect to couchbase ...Are you sure you are not under firewall ? try to run the standalone sample program in couch base cluster. if firewall is the case it should work.

Comment: I am running on the VM where everything is installed locally and no Firewall issues checked on that.

Comment: then you can give localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.169.101

Comment: This a static ip, that I am using, I could right data in couchbase from the cbc command, when I am accessing same thing programmatically  its failing.
For example below cbc commands id getting executed successfully.

cbc create --mode insert testId < /home/cloudera/Desktop/CouchData/sampat.json -U couchbase://192.168.169.101/testCouchBucket -u ****** -P ******